# Como realizar una consulta agrupada por una columna de tipo fecha-y-hora (DateTime) pero considerando el ultimo evento?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo una tabla de este estilo

[image: tabla]

necesito hacer una query en sql server que me diga el ultimo estado de la columna Status por Person por Phase y Por dia DateTime.

Tendria que quedar así.

[image: tabla-final]

Alguna idea de como deberia ser la query?

Comment: ¿Qué motor de sql utilizas (MySQL, Sql Server, Oracle, ...)?

Comment: Como comenta Roger, para poder contestar falta que digas el motor de la base de datos en que va ejecutar y el nombre de la tabla. Sin embargo es casi claro que lo que necesitas es una consulta agrupada. Investiga sobre la clausula GROUP BY de tu motor de base de datos.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imagenes con datos de ejemplo, publica los datos de manera textual.

Comment: Seria bueno que comiences con alguna query que se pruebes, asi te podremos ayudar mejor. Es decir por ejemplo que realices subconsultas para obtener, ejemplo de queries. Porque asi la pregunta es puntual. Te recomiendo para las proximas. Mas abajo dejo un ejemplo utilizando [RANK() de SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero el escenario:

```
Create table dbo.datosPersonas
             (
             Person   varchar(100)
           , Phase    varchar(100)
           , Status   varchar(100)
           , Datetime Datetime
             );
GO
Set DateFormat dmy;
Insert into dbo.datosPersonas(Person, Phase, Status, Datetime)
values
('Peter','Sleeping','Running','04/03/2019 13:06'),
('Peter','Sleeping','Running','04/03/2019 13:07'),
('Peter','Sleeping','Complete','04/03/2019 13:08'),
('Peter','Sleeping','Running','04/03/2019 13:09'),
('Peter','Sleeping','Complete','04/03/2019 13:10'),
('Peter','Sleeping','Running','05/03/2019 14:06'),
('Peter','Sleeping','Idle','06/03/2019 14:06'),
('John','Eating','Running','05/03/2019 14:06'),
('John','Eating','Complete','05/03/2019 14:06'),
('John','Eating','Running','05/03/2019 14:27'),
('John','Eating','Running','05/03/2019 14:27'),
('John','Eating','Running','05/03/2019 14:27'),
('John','Eating','Complete','05/03/2019 14:28'),
('Marcus','Eating','Running','07/03/2019 15:45'),
('Marcus','Studying','Complete','07/03/2019 15:46'),
('Marcus','Eating','Complete','07/03/2019 15:56');
```

Normalmente para las agrupaciones de datos, funcionan muy bien las funciones de ventana.

Para el ejemplo que solicitas, row_number nos puede ayudar, ya que a priori, lo que solicitas es numerar una serie de filas en función de una causística, que nos permita reiniciar la numeración y de esta obtener determinadas filas.

```
with c
     as (select row_number() over(PARTITION by Person
                                             , phase
                                             , cast(datetime as date)
                order by status
                       , datetime desc) as row
              , Person
              , Phase
              , Status
              , datetime
                from dbo.datosPersonas)
     Select   c.Person
            , c.Phase
            , c.Status
            , c.[Datetime]
            From c
            where c.row = 1
            order by Person desc;
```

[image: Resultado]

Una condición a tener en cuenta, es que el orden que se establece en over debiera de ser determinista. Por tanto no se debe de dar un caso de empate por el criterio de ordenación. En el caso de que se pueda dar, hay que revisar las posibilidades que nos brinda la cláusula over para "desempatar".

[Row Number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

[Cláusula over](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

Como menciones SQLServer y en tu frase

> necesito hacer una query en sql server que me diga **el ultimo estado de la columna Status por Person por Phase y Por dia DateTime**.

No sirve agrupar directamente por día, **porque es necesario el ultimo estado de ese dia**. Esto se puede hacer con subconsultas, pero me parece mas facil [RANK()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql).

Para eso en SQL Server tenemos una función que nos puede ayudar que es [RANK()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql), que es literalmente

> Devuelve el rango de cada fila en la partición de un conjunto de resultados. El rango de una fila es uno más el número de rangos anteriores a la fila en cuestión.

Es decir **"vamos a agrupar (particionar es el termino dentro de RANK) por Person por Phase y alli vamos a ordenar por Dia/Hora para que nos de este ranking de estatus"**

Para esto arme un ejemplo que lo puedes ejecutar online

- sqlfiddle > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/108a0/4

Para ver como te puede ayudar [RANK()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql), vamos a hacerlo como lo rankea por particion

```
  SELECT
    [Person],
    [Phase],
    [Status], 
    [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]), 
    [DateTime],
    RankingGroup = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Person],[Phase], CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime])
                   ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) 
  FROM TableDemo1
  ORDER BY [Person], [Phase], CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime])
```

El resultado de esto es (o deberia ser)

```
| Person | Phrase   | Status   | Date       | DateTime            | RankingGroup |
|--------|----------|----------|------------|---------------------|---|
| John   | Eating   | Complete | 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-05 14:28:00 | 1 |
| John   | Eating   | Running  | 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-05 14:27:00 | 2 |
| John   | Eating   | Complete | 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-05 14:26:00 | 3 |
| John   | Eating   | Running  | 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-05 14:06:00 | 4 |
| Marcus | Eating   | Complete | 2019-03-07 | 2019-03-07 15:56:00 | 1 |
| Marcus | Eating   | Running  | 2019-03-07 | 2019-03-07 15:45:00 | 2 |
| Marcus | Studying | Complete | 2019-03-07 | 2019-03-07 15:46:00 | 1 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Complete | 2019-03-04 | 2019-03-04 13:10:00 | 1 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Running  | 2019-03-04 | 2019-03-04 13:09:00 | 2 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Complete | 2019-03-04 | 2019-03-04 13:08:00 | 3 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Running  | 2019-03-04 | 2019-03-04 13:07:00 | 4 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Running  | 2019-03-04 | 2019-03-04 13:06:00 | 5 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Running  | 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-05 14:06:00 | 1 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Idle     | 2019-03-06 | 2019-03-06 14:06:00 | 1 |
```

si miras esta agrupado por Person, Phrase , Status, Date (sin hora) y el Ranking es por la fecha con hora DESC asi que el valor **1** es el que debe quedar como tu requerimiento inicial **el ultimo status del dia para dicha phrase**

Asi que nos queda filtrar

```
SELECT 
  [Person],[Phase],[Status],[DateTime]
FROM (SELECT
    [Person],
    [Phase],
    [Status], 
    [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]), 
    [DateTime],
    RankingGroup = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Person],[Phase], CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime])
                               ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) 
        FROM TableDemo1
    
) TEMP
WHERE RankingGroup = 1
```

El resultado final

```
| Person   | Phrase   | Status | Date                |
|--------|----------|----------|---------------------|
| John   | Eating   | Complete | 2019-03-05 14:28:00 |
| Marcus | Eating   | Complete | 2019-03-07 15:56:00 |
| Marcus | Studying | Complete | 2019-03-07 15:46:00 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Complete | 2019-03-04 13:10:00 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Running  | 2019-03-05 14:06:00 |
| Peter  | Sleeping | Idle     | 2019-03-06 14:06:00 |
```

Lo puedes probar online aqui

- sqlfiddle > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/108a0/4

Espero que sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar la consulta se requiere fundamentalmente:

- Uso de la clausula **GROUP BY** la funcion de agrupamiento **MAX** (Para determinar el evento mas reciente por Persona y Phase en cada día)
- Uso de tabla derivadas (Para utilizar la consulta agrupada que determina el evento mas reciente)
- Utilizar como nombre/alias de columna una palabra reservada del lenguaje. (En este caso referenciar como "DateTime" la columna en donde esta sacando el dato máximo y dárselo a la columna por la que va a agrupar).

Suponiendo que la tabla sobre la que se realizará la consulta se llama XXXX, y que la columna que contiene el dato al que se le va sacar el máximo se llama "DateTime"

En el motor de base de datos **SqlServer** y **Sybase ASE** sería:

```
select TablaDatos.Person, TablaDatos.Phase, TablaDatos.[Status], TablaDatos.[DateTime]
  from XXX as TablaDatos
       -- Tabla derivada UltimoEvento que calcula la fecha/hora en la que ocurre el
       -- ultimo evento de cada dia para Person, Phase
       inner join (select t1.Person,t1.Phase,cast(t1.[DateTime] as date) as Dia,MAX(t1.[DateTime]) as MaxDateTime
                     from XXX as t1
                    group by t1.Person,t1.Phase,cast(t1.[DateTime] as date)) as UltimoEvento
       on  TablaDatos.Person                  =UltimoEvento.Person
       and TablaDatos.Phase                   =UltimoEvento.Phase
       and cast(TablaDatos.[DateTime] as date)=UltimoEvento.Dia -- Coincide el dia
       and TablaDatos.[DateTime]              =UltimoEvento.[MaxDateTime] -- Coincide el momento
```

En esta consulta se utiliza una tabla derivada **UltimoEvento** donde se determina la fecha/hora en la que ocurre el ultimo **Status** agrupada por Person, Phase, y Dia

Determinado el momento en que ocurre el evento mas reciente se cruza nuevamente con la tabla que contiene los datos para determinar que status ocurrieron para Person y Phase en cada dia.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta he probado a ejecutar la query de sql server que has mencionado pero mi no realiza lo deseado me sigue devolviendo el mismo Status. Necesito que me indique el ultimo estado que hay por phase, persona y dia.

Comment: A que te refieres ahora con que te "sigue devolviendo el mismo Status"  Te estas refiriendo al valor de la columna "Status"?

Comment: exacto me esta devolviendo los mismo valores que hay en la columna Status no los modifica. Me interesa saber el ultimo estado que ha tenido cada fase de cada una de las personas en cada dia. Es decir si pedro ha comido y el estado era running en un dia si en ese mismo dia pedro vuelve a tener una fase comer y el estado es otro diferente por ejemplo complete solo me interesa el ultimo estado es decir que en ese dia pedro en esa fase de comer el estado final ha sido complete

Comment: Acabo de editarla respuesta solo para SqlServer ya que aclaraste en la pregunta que el motor es SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es agrupar por los campos **Person**, **Phase** y **Status** y utilizar la clausula `HAVING` para filtrar la fecha mas reciente

```
SELECT Person, 
    Phase,
    Status,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 112) AS Date
FROM TablaLoca
GROUP BY Person, Phase, Status
HAVING MAX(DateTime);
```

En este ejemplo estoy asumiendo que **DateTime** es una fecha y se puede tratar como tal. No lo pude probar por lo que puede tener que hacerse una corrección, pero lo importante es que para escenarios similares a los que planteas necesitars *agrupar* los datos y *filtrar los que cumplan* (having) una determinada condición. En este caso se la fecha mas reciente.

Comment: La consulta que propone daria el mismo valor para la columna calculada CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112) AS Date ya que esta tomando la hora del sistema e ignora los valores de la tabla de usuario

Comment: Tenes razon, se me paso. Ahora lo edito deberia utilizarse el campo DateTime en lugar de la hora del sistema

Comment: ¿Seguro que esa consulta funciona?